# What is the difference between phrases and entities in LUIS AI

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I'm trying to develop a BOT using Microsoft LUIS AI. Everything is going smoothly but I'm struggling to understand what's the difference between entities and phrases when you are creating your LUIS AI service.

Can someone explain this to me?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can consider the phrase list as a supplementary to recognize examples of an entity.

There is a comparison between the phrase list and list entity in the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-feature#when-to-use-phrase-lists-versus-list-entities)

**[When to use phrase list?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-feature#use-a-phrase-list)**

> With a phrase list, LUIS can still take context into account and
>   generalize to identify items that are similar to, but not an exact
>   match, as items in a list. If you need your LUIS app to be able to
>   generalize and identify new items in a category, use a phrase list.

**[When to use list entity?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-feature#dont-use-a-phrase-list)**

> A list entity explicitly defines every value an entity can take, and
>   only identifies values that match exactly. A list entity may be
>   appropriate for an app in which all instances of an entity are known
>   and don't change often. Examples are food items on a restaurant menu
>   that changes infrequently. If you need an exact text match of an
>   entity, do not use a phrase list.

Answer (score 0):

@Ali Heikal already explained the theory really well so I'm gonna add a real example that might help you clarify these concepts.

If the intent is "rent a car", one entity could be "car make" and the phrase lists could be the different car makes.

Intent: rent a car
Entities: CarMake, DateFrom, DateTo, City
CarMake is an entity of type List Entity with the following values: Ferrari, Porsche, Lamborghini, etc.
Phrase list: Near --> nearby, close, nearly. It's good to indicate synonyms.

Utterance: I want to rent a Ferrari from Monday to Saturday in New York
Intent: rent a car
Entity: 
-DateFrom: Monday
-DateTo: Saturday
-CarMake: Ferrari
-City: New York